# USB's storage capacity reduced to 2 MB from 16 GB

Tags: usb, system-installation, live-usb

I downloaded ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.

On Ubuntu's web page, I saw a link for making a bootable USB drive option, then I downloaded Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.3.3 and I made my USB bootable.

When installing the OS an error was found and installing not completed. After that I formated my USB but my USB's storage capacity reduced to 2 MB from 16 GB. How can I recover my USB size and install ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, but your USB stick is possibly broken. I had the same issue with 2GB USB stick and nothing helped me to restore the original size.

Comment: If you're already on Ubuntu or have access to any Ubuntu system, hook your pen drive and open `Disk Utility` and see if your pen drive has any partitions set.

Comment: First use the commands in cmd, look in the comments and then i used [HPUSBDISK](http://download.cnet.com/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool/3000-2094_4-10974082.html) to format the usb.

Answer (score 74):

Since there is no working answer yet, I post this:

The problem is that the remaining space of your USB flash disk has become unallocated. To repair it, use diskpart (in windows):

- Open command line (cmd) and type `diskpart`. Allow the windows to run it.
- type `list disk`, and find the number of your USB flash disk.
- type `select disk X`, and type the number of the USB disk instead of `X`.It should say that disk X is now selected.
- type `clean`.
- type `create partition primary`.

Now you should be able to use the flash disk as before. (You have to format it first)

Comment: This is a genuine working method :)

Comment: Kinda strange that you can't do this from the Disk Management console (`diskmgmt.msc`)

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: 2 yrs after, this is still a great find. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much. You'd think Ubuntu would warn people that USB drives used to make a bootable stick can't simply be re-formatted for reuse with Windows machines....

Comment: @Mostafa, you are a God in my book. Thanks a lot!

Comment: great solution which worked for me

Comment: Your are just a genius.

Comment: didn't work in first attempt but after 2 attempts it worked, thanks a lot

Comment: Why are people upvoting a Windows solution on Ask Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

first of all open disk management.
click on removable disk or pen drive you choose.
right click on it and see the total space (sum of allocated and unallocated space)
if the size is less than total space then follow these step.
open cmd (in administrator mode)
type "diskpart"
press enter
type "list volume"
press enter
type "select volume 6"
{select the removable disk option such as 1,2,3}
press enter
type "clean"
press enter
then exit cmd go to disk management.
right click on removable disk(your pendrive volume)
open new voulume 
then new partition wizard will start .
then click next until it is finished.
now see your pen drive capacity it is changed!!!!!!!

thank you for reading this !!!!!!!!
please comment if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Disk Utility that comes with Ubuntu and check that the Flash Drive's partition is actually using the whole 16gb, it may be that during the USB Installer's usage it screwed up the partition tables...  To fix this you can remove any partitions inside the Disk Utility for that particular device and re-add them again ready for formatting properly...

Answer (score 0):

if you are on  windows 7 and dont have any linux, right click the my computer, then click Manage.
ther you can format the usb and your other disk drives.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but here is a solution for Ubuntu since the only complete answer here is for Windows (on AskUbuntu...).

This CLI solution uses [fdisk](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fdisk.8.html) on Ubuntu 18.04. In this example, I am using a drive that has 64 GB total space, but displays only 512MB as available.

1. Open up a terminal using `Ctrl + Alt + t`. Identify the USB drive using the command `sudo fdisk -l`. This will output all of your mounted disks and devices, with an individual entry looking something like:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 57.8 GiB, 62058921984 bytes, 121208832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbbd6109c

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 1050623 1048576  512M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

2. Find your USB drive from the list based on the expected size in bytes. You will likely see two entries for your one USB drive like above: one for `Disk` (a portion of the drive which is accessible to you) and one for `Device` (the total space on the drive). In the original question, the `Disk` entry would show 2 MB of space, and `Device` would show 16 GB.

We can now reclaim this space so that all of it is accessible to you (instead of just the 2 MB in `Disk`).

3. Make a note of the `Disk`'s name; in this example, this would be `/dev/sda`. **NOTE: it is very important the identify the name for your drive correctly since we will be erasing the data on it** -- you don't want to accidentally choose your hard drive and erase personal data!
4. Load the drive into fdisk with the command `sudo fdisk /drive/name`, replacing `/drive/name` with the name you from Step 3 (like `/dev/sda`). This will start up the `fdisk` CLI interface (not your normal terminal); you can show available commands by entering `m`.

   - Enter `p` to confirm that this is the drive you found in Step 3. Enter `d` to delete the existing `Device` partition.
   - Enter `n` to create a new partition. Press enter for each option to get the defaults (one partition that is the max size of your USB drive). You can enter in other values, e.g. if you want more than one partition. Enter `p` again to check the new partition, which should be different than in Step 5.
   - Enter `w` to save these changes and return to the normal terminal.
5. Add a file system -- if you don't know about file systems but want to use this drive with both Ubuntu and Windows, a good choice is NTFS. Enter `mkfs.ntfs -f /drive/name` to format the drive. See below* for more info.
6. Mount the drive. A good walkthrough is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/290883/931761), but one quick way to do this is:

```
sudo mkdir /media/your_drive
sudo mount /drive/name /media/your_drive
```

The full space of your drive should now be accessible!

---

*About file systems: NTFS is compatible with both Ubuntu and Windows, but there are better options such as ext4 (Linux), exFAT (Win), FAT32 (both), etc. that you can/should use if you don't need the drive for both Linux and Windows -- I defer discussion of file systems to [other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413044/is-there-a-better-option-other-than-ntfs-for-a-shared-hd-between-ubuntu-and-wind?rq=1) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/a/164738/931761).