# usb memory loss while formatting

Tags: usb-drive

while formatting the pendrive (32 GB), I pulled it out, unintentionally. Now the pendrive is recognized but only with 760 MB. How it get back the pendrive to full capacity?

Comment: What's happen if you try to reformate it ?
Also there are already some pages about this problem, i don't know if it's working https://askubuntu.com/questions/289971/usbs-storage-capacity-reduced-to-2-mb-from-16-gb

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Have you tried to format it again? If the result persists, please [edit] your question to add the output of the command `lsblk`. Don’t forget to [format it as code](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.. 
as it is said in [howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17001/how-to-format-a-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-using-gparted/), we can install `gparted` and select the device that needed to be recoverd and format it again as ntfs or ext3/ext4. The link provided above gives explanation regarding how to format a usb drive in ubuntu using gparted.
Hope this answer would be helpful to the community.
I appreciate the correction@guiverc

Comment: I suggest you provide *context for your link* as per https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer, ie. that you used `gparted` to...  as per link

Comment: I did not get What you were trying to tell, should I give the link related to askubuntu?

Comment: No your link is fine, but your answer is really just follow & read the link.  If you read the how-to-answer it tells you "*Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*"

Answer (score 0):

Just adding additional solution. Try to format with mkusb.

[Click here for mkusb description](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui)

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mkusb
```

It comes with good GUI support. Just format as mentioned in this link

[Click here to know how to format usb with mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

You will get back the last partition just like a magic.