# Is it okay to use a ntfs partition for data to be accessed by windows 7 and ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, ntfs

Constantly, I use windows and ubuntu and need to access files on both systems. It sucks to be copying files back and forth and sometimes I forget some file and I have to restart several times. To resolve this I created the following partitions

```
Device     Boot     Start             End   Blocks      Id System 
/dev/sda1    *       2048         1026047   512000       7 HPFS / NTFS / exFAT 
/dev/sda2       1,026,048      35,842,047   17,408,000  27 Hidden NTFS WinRE 
/dev/sda3        35842048       247212031   105684992    7 HPFS / NTFS / exFAT 
/dev/sda4     247,214,017   1,250,263,039   501,524,511+ f Win95 (LBA) Extended Partition 
/dev/sda5       247214080      1053323263   403054592    7 HPFS / NTFS / exFAT 
/dev/sda6   1,053,327,360   1,233,903,615   90,288,128  83 Linux 
/dev/sda7   1,233,905,664   1,250,263,039    8,178,688  82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Some people and websites say that doing so is not recommended. Will I have problems?

Comment: I would suggest `fat32`

Comment: I would suggest looking into `unix2dos`

Comment: @dan08 - that has a file size limit of 4GB, and cannot use symlinks. I would use (and do use) a NTFS partition set to be mounted on boot in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: As far as your home directory is a Unix filesystem, there are no problems that I know to symlink for example `~/Documents` or `~/Pictures` to a NTFS partition. `$HOME` however should be able to full implement Unix permission semantics, otherwise you'll have problems for example with `ssh` and `gpg`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty good link in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164728/should-i-choose-exfat-or-ntfs-for-a-shared-partition-in-a-dual-boot-system/164738#164738) about this.  The basics are that generally ntfs is a good choice for a shared partition, although Ubuntu does not have great support for repairing ntfs partitions.