# How to use badblocks to scan a certain /dev/sdX to deal with bad sectors

Tags: badblocks

I need to do partitioning to an NTFS drive that gparted said it has bad sectors. ([I made a question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400609/i-need-help-with-increasing-the-size-of-the-file-system-partition-partitioning))

Anyways I followed its advice of using `chkdsk` on windows and restarted it twice but gparted still says it has bad sectors.

I thought I'd try another method and found this program (badblocks). I looked up the documentation but the program seems a bit dangerous to use on my own. ([Here's the documentation](http://www.clearfoundation.com/docs/man/index.php?s=8&n=badblocks))

I can't figure out the command I need to use. ... also if there's a better suggestion for a program that can help me don't hesitate. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo badblocks -nvs /dev/sdX` and replace sdX with the partition you want

`-nvs` would make a non destructive test and would show the progress and "would give a verbose output" (which means a more explicit output)