# Repartitioning alternatives?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Out of the 320gb of hard drive space my computer came with, only 33 GB were partitioned to Ubuntu, with the rest of the space (288 GB or so) going to windows NTFS. Of those 33 GB, 11 GB are allocated to the system and 20 GB to the home directory; 2 more GB are swap and one last gigabyte is unallocated.

As I currently stand, I am running 13.04 and my root partition is 93% full with very little on my desktop. In order to repartition my disk, I'll need to upgrade to 13.10 as I can't find a 13.04 ISO on the Ubuntu website; once I do that I'll boot into a live USB system and repartition from there.

Is there some way I can just delete the Windows partition and reallocate? I don't think I can, but I'm asking anyway.

Also, can I reassign the unallocated space (all 1 GB of it) to my filesystem?

Comment: If you are looking to update Ubuntu and you want to completely get rid of Windows, then the simplest, fastest, and least-risky thing to do is simply backup all of your data and do a fresh install of the latest Ubuntu; choose to erase entire disk and install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format(delete) the windows partition from Ubuntu (using gparted) but you can't resize an active filesystem!  To add space to Ubuntu you need to do it from "somewhere else" and of course your best option is a live usb. this question may help you [I need help with increasing the size of the file-system partition. Partitioning-o-phobia!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400609/i-need-help-with-increasing-the-size-of-the-file-system-partition-partitioning) feed me back :)

p.s: there's no need whatsoever to upgrade Ubuntu. you  wouldn't be doing partitioning from it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

No need for reinstall with live CD!!

*gparted* is the best partitioner software i have ever used, (and i have used a fair few Win32 versions) boot up Ubuntu and search for it in the software center

make sure that you have defraged your NTFS partition before altering any partition sizes to minimize any messups that may happen from doing so.

Back up all your data would be the best bet, just in case. changing partition sizes may cause data loss.

just shrink the NTFS part, add a new EXT partition
Ubuntu will see it as a new HDD

If you are seriously wanting the file system to have the extra space, then booting from LiveCD will free up the file system on the HDD (*gparted* will no longer show the blue box around that particular partition), then you can grow this partition in the safest manner.

if you want rid of the windows partition altogether then just delete the NTFS partition, allocating that section to EXT will get rid of it for good. Just remember to give yourself room for the Linux-swap partition (best practice is usually 2xRAM when under 2gb of ram)
Job done.