# How to resize the root partition using GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm new to [GParted](https://gparted.org/). I have to resize a partition that contains the root file system which is full. Previously, I had Windows installed on my system. I use a 250GB hard drive and it was divided into three drives namely the C, D and E drive. After this, I installed Ubuntu and used the existing NTFS file system to install Ubuntu.

Now, I need to resize the partition mounted as the root file system because it is full.

Below is the screenshot of GParted:

[image: GParted showing partitions]

What should I do to increase the size of `/dev/sda6` without any data loss?

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/404361/extending-my-root-paritition) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/400609/i-need-help-with-increasing-the-size-of-the-file-system-partition-partitioning)

Comment: @AvinashRaj I saw it . But, my root /dev/sda6 is locked I cannot unmount it, so what should I do to move the free space in /dev/sda3 to the right of /dev/sda6

Comment: you have to boot from Ubuntu live disk.So that you can be able to resize your Ubuntu partition.Before resizing, make that the partition you want to be resized should be unmounted.See the full answer.

Comment: The main problem for you, as Avinash pointed out, is that you are trying to resize a mounted partition...since it is your root partition you cannot unmount it because your system is currently running off of it. So the answer provided kamil is in my opinion the fastest and simplest way to go.

Comment: Why is this question off-topic? It is not specific to a particular release.

Comment: This question can still be relevant to other Ubuntu versions - it is not *version specific* in the latest edit, and just because it said 12.04 doesn't mean it's not still useful/relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 19):

1. Download the GParted Live CD ISO from [here](https://gparted.org/download.php) and burn it using Brasero.
2. Boot from it.
   [image: GRUB GParted screen]
3. Skip change of keyboard mapping.
   [image: keymaps handling dialog]
4. To start up the default graphical environment Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   [image: mode selection dialog]
5. GParted is now running.
   [image: Running GParted]

Comment: This is a dangerous answer that doesn't address the 'how-to' of resizing root, and remapping the UUID is a critical part of that.

Comment: dangerous!! I think he knows what GParted is.