# Extend root partition size

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted

I have this in GParted. [image] I want to extend my `/` filesystem (by eventually reducing the `/home` partition). I've seen [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition), but the answers doesn't fit my need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) Or [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430956/how-to-resize-the-root-partition-using-gparted) or [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime) or any of many more.

Comment: If you can reduce sda5 then this should be easy.

Comment: @heynnema, What about  reducing sda7 (`/home`) ?

Comment: Either one. sda5 just seems like a lot of wasted space though.