# Unable to Resize Root Partition with unallocated space(Weird Partition Arrangement)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Have seen a few questions regarding this but didn't help my case.

I have installed Ubuntu 17.04 alongside Windows 8 using a dual boot setup(Have to boot into ubuntu using f9 key and selecting device to boot.Have an HP laptop so grub does not show up by default.)

So i have some unallocated space and i would like to increase the size of my root partition by using the unallocated space plus it's current size.

Here is a picture of my results from Gparted using Ubuntu Live Disk [Gparted Screen shot of System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgv6a.jpg)

The unallocated space shown in the picture needs to be added to the partition name /dev/sda9

I believe i cannot use the normal "move to left and resize approach" as shown here.
[Reference Question Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430956/how-to-resize-the-root-partition-using-gparted)

Do tell me if it might be possible to resize my system in the first place.I didn't realize this that i would be facing such space shortage as i have just finished setting up the system.

Comment: @Terrance -- since sda11 can't be moved, the only way to get space into sda9 is to make a new partition, and mount it into a folder in sda9 or to reinstall. In this instance a reinstall is the best solution since Ubuntu isn't installed in EFI mode.

Comment: @ravery You win.  However, sda6 will still have to be moved to reclaim the 24GB to be used in the reinstallation of Ubuntu even in UEFI mode.

Comment: @Terrance -- yes sda6, not sda7 thank you for the correction. the small space after sda7 probably can't be reclaimed, unless added to sda7, because of partition alignment.

Comment: 1MB unallocated space is best just to leave it alone.  https://superuser.com/questions/847775/gparted-leaves-1mb-unallocated-space-at-end-of-external-hdd-override-alternativ

Comment: @ravery, he can move sda9... might have to reinstall grub afterwords, but it can be moved.  Also it is 95 mb but only needs to be 1 mb so it could be shrunk at the same time.

Comment: @psusi - moving sda11 will break the boot, grub would have to be reinstalled. However, Windows is in EFI mode and Ubuntu is in Legacy mode, this can cause difficulty with reinstalling grub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being an HP computer has nothing to do with grub not showing. The reason that you are having trouble with grub, is because you installed ubuntu in Legacy mode instead of EFI mode. If you reinstall in EFI mode then you won't have to press F9, grub will boot and allow you to choose which OS to load.

#### What I would do:

It is best to use Windows to manipulate Windows' partitions. Start Window and using the disk manager, move /sda6 to the right. Then delete the linux partitions.
Next, reboot while pressing the <kbd>F10</kbd> to get to the system settings menu. Turn off legacy boot to insure that ubuntu boots in EFI mode.
After installing Ubuntu, Press <kbd>F10</kbd> while booting and change the OS boot selection to Ubuntu. Now grub will boot and allow you to select Windows or Ubuntu.

#### If you don't want to reinstall:

I assume /sda9 is the root partition and sda12 is a /home partition. If this is the case, then root is large enough. You probably want to add space to the home partition (sda12).
Use windows to move /sda6 to the right. then use gparted to add the free space to /sda12.

Comment: Okay.So with my current setup i cannot add extra space to root without reinstalling right? And extra space for home will not be needed as i have mounted my other partitions and i keep all my stuff there.

Comment: @DhruvMarwha -- correct. With a seperate /home partition, 19GB is plenty of space for root. Just remember to remove old kernels. However, I would reinstall anyway because you have both OS's in different boot modes. That is why you have to use F9 to select which to boot.

Comment: Hmm.Ok.Maybe i might reinstall later as right now i do not have very good internet access so updating Ubuntu properly will not be possible.

Comment: Ravery-can you help me with another issue that I am having? I did the reinstall of my Ubuntu system but when I try to set the priority of the os in bios,it does not save the settings.Even though I save and exit,it places the windows boot manager on top and Ubuntu below.