# Encrypted an external hard drive on macOS; now I cannot load on Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, mac

As the title says, I formatted, encrypted, and then filled an external hard drive using macOS. Now I'd like to transfer that data to a new machine running Ubuntu. Following [this AU post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318987/ubuntu-doesnt-see-external-usb-hard-disk), I first verified the volume is available:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.84 TiB, 2000365289472 bytes, 3906963456 sectors
Disk model: My Passport 0820
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7400627C-6C10-4D3F-BE4C-C4CDC8084533

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1          40     409639     409600  200M EFI System
/dev/sdc2      409640 3906701271 3906291632  1.8T Apple Core storage
/dev/sdc3  3906701272 3906963415     262144  128M Apple boot
```

When I try to mount this volume, I get the following error:

```bsh
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc ~/Desktop/external/
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Following [this AU post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548417/cant-mount-ntfs-drive-ntfs-signature-is-missing), I also tried mounting the partition, not the hard disk itself,

```bsh
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc2 ~/Desktop/external/
```

but get the same error. Trying this command on `/dev/sdc1` does not error via the terminal

```bsh
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 ~/Desktop/external/
$ ls ~/Desktop/external/
```

however, the directory is still empty. I'm also unable to unmount these directories:

[image]

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: **How** is the volume encrypted? Are you using an Apple/Mac proprietary file system and/or encryption standard? Are you using NTFS for any particular reason (a proprietary *Windows* file system)?  You need to use an encryption standard that is supported by **BOTH** operating systems.  If you can't get LUKS to work in MacOS then maybe Veracrypt?

Answer (score 0):

Complicated.

You need to follow these instructions:

https://github.com/libyal/libfvde/wiki/Mounting

Previous installation of these applications:

https://github.com/libyal/libfvde

https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse