# NTFS signature is missing. Volume is corrupt

Tags: mount, ntfs, read-only

I have a remote VPS with Ubuntu 20.04 which worked well yesterday. Today I found out the whole disc is read only. I can not write anymore nor as sudo nor the root. After the search I found command which should fix it https://askubuntu.com/a/1273263/568046

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2
```

This command throws me an error:

```
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

Command chkdsk does not exist. After this command all programs are dead. I can run commands like systemctl status apache2 but can not start it any more.
Does somebody know what it means? Thanks for any help.

Comment: `chkdsk` is a **Windows** tool. And you need Windows tools to try fixing NTFS.

Comment: What is the solution for my VPS?

Comment: I found this `fsck /dev/sda2` and it ask me to fix filesystem. Can I run the fix?

Comment: Command writes: /dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix<y>?

Comment: Not a solution but *not using* NTFS with Linux systems would have prevented that. Again, you need Windows to error correct NTFS formatted partitions, the `ntfsfix` command can at best signal the drive to be checked (and, if possible, corrected) at the boot time of an Windows instance. This is assuming you have tried a command for NTFS because you have NTFS but it isn't clear that you know what you're doing? The previous comment/question suggests exactly that.

Comment: If the file system is NOT NTFS but some EXTn typicall of Linux thenh yes, `fsck` may work.

Comment: It is true that I dont understand what it means that filesystem is corrupted.

Comment: Please fsck ask me this > Deleted inode 23592984 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? Can I do it?

Comment: Yes, you can and that's probably the last chance to fix it. You really need to understand the different file system, know *exactly* which ones you have (there are many currently supported for Linux) and the possibilities for error correction and the tools to use for each one. NTFS is a Microsoft proprietary file system that is now the standard for Windows installations. All modern Linux distros can read/write to NTFS but not correct it .

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. It works. fsck + restart fix it. Thanks again.