# Mount Problem Error

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs

I am unable to load windows 8.1 it gives me this message 
"Disk read error occurred" 
and refresh not working so trying to recover my files through Ubuntu 14.04. I try to access the hard drive,but get the error message as below.
I can't load windows to turn off the fast boot,So is there any other solution I can use to access my files in Windows through Ubuntu.

```
  Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/itsfoss/01BC76G7Z2628FB0: 
  Command-line `mount -t “ntfs” - 
  “uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177″
  “/dev/sda5″ “/media/itsfoss/01BC76G7Z2628FB0″‘ exited with non-zero 
  exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).

  Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
  Failed to mount ‘/dev/sda5′: Operation not permitted
  The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
  Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
  read-only with the ‘ro’ mount option.
```

Comment: check here http://askubuntu.com/questions/47700/fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-without-windows

Comment: Windows is in hibernation mode, which prevents it from mounting. Try adding `-f` to your mount command.

Comment: @JoKeR  I tried to Install ntfs-3g as suggested in that post ,but the thing is  when I run  the command   ntfsfix /dev/sda5   it says Error opening '/dev/sda5': Permission denied
and thats because windows is  in fast restarting mode and i cant turn that off

Comment: did you run it with `sudo`?