# My external hard drive won't mount. I am using Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: mount, 14.10

The error message is:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at media/dennis/TOSHIBA EXT :Command-line 'mount-t "ntfs"_o
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177"
"/dev/sdb1""media/dennis/TOSHIBA EXT"' exited with non-zero exit status13:$MFTMirr does not match $MFT(recordo).

Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1':Input/output error

NTFS is either inconsistent,or there is a hardware fault, or it's a 
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk/f on windows then 
reboot into windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very 
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/Fake RAID then first activate it 
and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/directory, (e.g. 
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation for more details.

(udisks-error-quark,0)
```

Comment: this tutorial about [ntfsfix](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/ntfs-partition-repair-and-recovery-in-linux/) may help you in case you dont have windows machine available, but it's always best to fix it with a win machine, so use at your own risk, i've used it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The third paragraph says NTFS is inconsistent, and tells you how to fix it with Windows. NTFS is a Microsoft secret that Linux can't fix.

Also see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729397/cant-mount-or-fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-on-working-hdd/729466?s=7%7C0.9522#729466).