# Ubuntu 16.04 won't boot after Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, windows

I'm having a problem booting Ubuntu 16.04 after using windows 10 (I have fast boot enabled). But, as i understand, it should work.
This is my disk setup:

- **Windows Partition** (OS and programs) <- not mounted in ubuntu
- **Shared Ntfs Partition** (Stuff) <- auto-mounted in ubuntu as nfts-3g
- **Ubuntu Partition**

As I get, Windows Fast Boot make some sort of "shutdown/hibernate" which leaves the disk in an unsafe state after shutting down. But should this affect my "SHARED PARTITION" too? Because, after I remove the auto mount in the /etc/fstab file, ubuntu boots normally. Once I enter, if i try to mount the disk, this pops up:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda8 at /media/pablo/7A02A0B456DA5406:
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda8"
"/media/pablo/7A02A0B456DA5406"' exited with non-zero exit status 14:
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0). Metadata kept in
Windows cache, refused to mount. Failed to mount '/dev/sda8':
Operation not permitted The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state.
Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast
restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Hope you can give me some ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: it does affect shared partition, unfortunately you'll have to turn fast boot off

Comment: after you turn fast boot off, try this out if you're shared ntfs partition still isn't working http://askubuntu.com/a/47711/665251

Comment: Shut off both [Fast Startup](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [Hibernate](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) in Windows. Note that many EFIs have a feature called "fast start" or something similar. This feature is completely unrelated to the Windows Fast Startup feature, and should not cause the type of problem you're describing. It's the *Windows* Fast Startup feature that can cause filesystem damage in a dual-boot environment.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make windows Fast-Boot to only leave in thar "hibernated" state the partiton that contains the OS files, and not the data one... ?
Thanks for all the answers!!!