# External HDD not unmounted properly and now not working correctly

Tags: hard-drive

I recently gave my external HDD away to a Windows user and now I can't write anything to it nor read files on it, but it still shows folders and filenames in the file manager. I think he did not unmount the drive. I would just format it, but I want to keep the Data and I can't copy anything from it. What should I do?

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/47700/fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-without-windows

Comment: Possibly your friend had activated `fast boot`, so that Windows did not really shutdown but wrote a hibernation file `hiberfil.sys`. How to remove this file from Linux is described for example (here)https://www.howtogeek.com/236807/how-to-mount-your-windows-10-or-8-system-drive-on-linux/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He likely had "Fast Start' enabled. Thus the drive is hibernated.

If you have a access to a Windows computer, start Windows twice with the drive plugged in, then eject it before turning off Windows.

Comment: Thanks that helped! now i can read and write again to the drive :)