# Help mounting an external drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I had a power supply failure on my old machine which seems to have taken out the motherboard and hard drive. Luckily, I had backed up my important data to a Seagate FreeAgent drive. I bought a new machine and have both windows 7 and ubuntu 18.04 on it. However, neither seems to be able to access the drive. Both systems seem to recognize that it exists, but it doesn't mount. I've tried

```
ls /dev/ | grep sd
```

with both the drive inserted and not, making sure it was the only usb device other than mouse and keyboard. The drive seems to be

```
sdb
```

The relevant output of

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

is

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 232.9 GiB, 250059349504 bytes, 488397167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Trying to follow along with the Ubuntu help page, I tried

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb /media/external
```

The output is:

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

*How should I proceed?*

Edit:
Thanks for the help! As suggested, tried

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/external
```

which produced
    ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory

```
ntfs-3g 2017.3.23 integrated FUSE 28 - Third Generation NTFS Driver
    Configuration type 7, XATTRS are on, POSIX ACLS are on
```

along with some copyright notices. I then tried

```
parted --list
```

which produced

```
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system). /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label
Model: MATSHITA DVD+-RW SW820 (scsi)                                      
Disk /dev/sr0: 77.2MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

If I try

```
lsblk
```

I get

`NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop1    7:1    0 140.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop2    7:2    0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/260
loop3    7:3    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
loop4    7:4    0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
loop5    7:5    0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop6    7:6    0 195.2M  1 loop /snap/vlc/555
loop7    7:7    0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/139
loop8    7:8    0  88.2M  1 loop /snap/core/5897
loop9    7:9    0  34.6M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop10   7:10   0  34.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop11   7:11   0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
loop12   7:12   0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop13   7:13   0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop14   7:14   0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/103
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 233.1G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 232.6G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  73.7M  0 rom  /media/zvacanti/setup`

The drive is still connected, so I'm not sure why I don't see it there. I DO see it in the disks utility, or at least something labeled "sdb". The disk wasn't plugged in when the system crashed, I made the backup and then just put it away in a drawer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu) as there are no partitions visible on your disk the duplicate is what you need.  **Good luck!** (You'll need it!)

Comment: It seems there is no patititons on sdb. Also your parted output is useless, sr0 is your optical drive.

Comment: Am I basically out of luck, then? The data's gone?

Comment: As suggested, I followed [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu), which suggested using testdisk. This worked to get the backup back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The devil is in the details of the output, especially:

```
Or the whole disk instead of a partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)
```

so you're trying to mount a disk, not a partition so instead do a:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/external
```

to mount the first `1` partition on the second disk `sdb` (`sdb1`) and if that fails, do a:

```
parted --list
```

and take the number(s) that shows up for `sdb` as you might have multiple partitions on one disk. <sub><sup>(In Windows speak: multiple drives on one disk)</sup></sub>

If the drive would have been attached *while the machine crashed* (It shouldn't have been, that's what we call *offline backups*) [try this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47700/fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-without-windows).