# i can not access windows 10 when i install ubunte 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

i install ubuntu 18.04 with windows 10 in my laptop i do not perhaps delete the boot partitions of windows.
but later after ubuntu finished installed,i try to access back to windows 10 by choosing the option of windows 10 while booting it shows error that not allow me to access windows 10 .
The error shown in blue screen and it said error code :0x000000f and your PC device need to be repaired
i try to use this commend 
sudo parted -l; sudo update-grub
but the problem it still happened 
so what i can do to solve this problem??

thanks

Comment: What does `sudo parted -l` show? [edit] your question and add output.

Comment: Model: ATA Hitachi HTS72757 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB  primary
 2      106MB   630MB  524MB  primary  ntfs         boot
 3      630MB   161GB  161GB  primary  ext4
 4      161GB   750GB  589GB  primary  ntfs

Answer (score 0):

Is Windows UEFI or BIOS install? Just be sure to boot Ubuntu live installer in same boot mode and use ppa to add Boot-Repair. If still issues post link to summary report.

Further you can boot from your Ubuntu live CD/ USB and follow instructions given in link of [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) page. Follow the second option:

**install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu**

- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
> ```

And follow **Recommended repair** for more detail.

You can also refer to website of [Boot-Repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/)

Comment: don't forget to keep a copy of paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX.

Comment: Ok , i did that and i got  this paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX. , and i restart my computer but the problem it same i can not access my windows 10 so what shill i do ?

Comment: Please edit your question and paste link to pastebin and also share if boot-repair success message and is if you still getting same error on windows boot.

Comment: that is the link http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vS8wYNx3Kz/,,and still i get same error in windows boot

Comment: It says NTFS signature is missing. So Read this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/47700/fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-without-windows and run the ntfsfix command on your NTFS partition. Backup important data from Windows disk.

Comment: I do not really understand what they explain in the post . can you please explain to me?

Comment: NTFS is a proprietary file system developed by Microsoft for the Windows operating system.. In linux there are commands to fix NTFS but limited. Boot your windows install media and run chkdsk.

Comment: i can not boot my windows

Comment: Please read carefully I did not write to boot installed window but to boot from Windows install Media.

Comment: nstall ntfs-3g with sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g. Then run the ntfsfix command on your NTFS partition.

For example:

ntfsfix /dev/hda6.........                                                                                                                                                  I try this one and when i write 
ntfsfix /dev/hda6   for my device it show to me this "Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sda4."

Comment: when i try to access windows 10 it shows blue screen include this massage                ""Recovery your PC/Device needs to be repaired A required device is not connected or can not be accessed error code :0x000000f you will need to use recovery tools. if you do not have any installation media (like a disc or USB device ), contact your PC administrator or PC/Device manufacture.""

Comment: @programmer I shall advice you please get help of a professional if possible to get it fixed. I tell you why: there is no sda6 in your system. It is /dev/sda1 and sda2.  Please refer this https://www.kapilarya.com/how-to-fix-error-0xc000000f-the-boot-selection-failed-because-a-required-device-is-inaccessible. Please proceed only if you know what are you doing.

Comment: yes i did not use sda6 i use another one sda4 which is in my system .