# my win10 crashed so i want to install ubuntu instead and running into several problems

Tags: boot, hibernate

my win10 crashed (unmountable boot volume error), so I brutally shut it down, and tried to install ubuntu instead of my win 10 (I do not any back up, just erase and install ubuntu). I downloaded ubuntu iso and created a flash bootable USB from my mac using Etcher.
All goes great, till it got stuck in installation with the error: input/output error during read on /dev/sda

from googling around, i understood that my windows is still hibernating and not completely shut-down and this might be the reason for this error. I just want to format this hd and install ubuntu from scratch. is there a way to do it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Input/output error indicates that your disk is broken. Installing Ubuntu on whole disk don't care about what is on the disk or if Windows was hibernating or not earlier. Maaybe the Windows crash was because of the bad disk.

Comment: After booting to "live" Ubuntu from USB, you can use smartctl to check for physical problems on disk: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/smartctl.8.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix your windows 10 OS, follow [This Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/47711/1126651).

Also, you can do this above, and repair the partition. after that, open the Command prompt and type `powercfg -h off`. it will delete the `hiberfile.sys` and won't hibernate.
probably it can't be fixed, because it's hibernated.

**Edit**: i already tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/47711/1126651) on my broken WIndows 7 OS (UNMOUTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME) and it fixed it. i don't know how it will work if the OS is hibernated.

Comment: For me this did not help and I really don't know what else to do. The HD is relatively new ssd HD. I'm pretty sure that it is not dead... Just want to format it and start from scratch...

Comment: "new" does not mean it won't fail. Actually, hard drive failure rates resemble a "bathtub curve" (look it up).  They have high failure rates early on.  All evidence of your issue points to dying hardware.

Comment: The hard drive may be faulty, like if you dropped it on the floor. also the issue is solvable by replacing the hard drive.