# GRUB menu resets when Windows selected. Dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10,

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, windows-10

I'v been using a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on my desktop for almost a year. It however stopped working recently. The GRUB menu appears at start as usual but when I select windows, it simply resets the GRUB menu without showing any error. I can still login to Ubuntu without problem. I tried booting to windows directly through the motherboard interface but it just leads me to the GRUB menu.

1. I followed the suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix) on trying the boot-repair several times with no help. My boot info summary is here http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3vrb9cpTvR/
2. I thought the disk might be corrupted so I tried ntfsfix as suggested in [Fix corrupt NTFS partition without Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47700/fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-without-windows) but it did not resolve the problem. (It did break my nvidia driver on Ubuntu though, not sure why)
3. I then tried starting with my windows install usb and tried to recover by restoring a previous restore point. The restoring succeeded according to the software but the GRUB menu behavior remains the same. I also tried window's startup repair and it claims it repaired it successfully but the GRUB menu problem remains.

I tried boot-repair again after restoring windows but nothing have changed.

My OS are all installed on a NVMe ssd, I believe the MBR is at /dev/nvme0n1p2 and windows is at /dev/nvme0n1p4. /dev/nvme0n1p1 is windows recovery environment.

I have been aware of the common dual boot problems such as windows fast startup and have disabled it. At this point I have no idea whats the problem and not sure what to check next.

Please help me diagnose this problem. Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If Windows doesn't boot directly in UEFI boot then it needs repairs. No Linux tool can really repair NTFS partitions, Windows tools are needed for that. Please obtain and boot from Windows installation media, follow instructions that are outside of the scope of AskUbuntu (it's a Windows problem).

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. That includes fast start up off, no chkdsk required & UEFI secure boot off. Secure Boot does not currently work with grub as something about the signed drivers and transfer from grub to Windows, even if grub is Secure Boot configured. Note that Windows updates may update UEFI, which updates UEFI settings and turn UEFI Secure boot back on. And Windows update may turn Windows fast start up back on. After Windows updates, settings may need to be reviewed.